# How to specify source for a dependency declared in gemspec?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Bundler [since v1.7](http://bundler.io/v1.7/man/gemfile.5.html#GLOBAL-SOURCES-source-) issues a warning when more than one global source is specified in the `gemfile`. You can use [source blocks](http://bundler.io/v1.7/man/gemfile.5.html#BLOCK-FORM-OF-SOURCE-GIT-PATH-GROUP-and-PLATFORMS) to specify which gems should come from a given source, but the [source](http://bundler.io/v1.7/man/gemfile.5.html#SOURCE-source-) option for individual gems does not work in the `gemspec`.

How can one specify the source for a dependency in the gemspec? E.g.

```
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # Gemspec contents omitted for brevity 

  # Lets say this one comes from RubyGems.org 
  s.add_runtime_dependency 'aruntimedep', '~> 1.0'

  # And this one needs to be sourced from a private gem server
  s.add_development_dependency 'adevdep',  '~> 3.0'

  # Note, Bundler throws an error in this case
  # s.add_development_dependency 'adevdep',  '~> 3.0', :source => "mygemserver.org"

end
```

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't specify the source in `.gemspec` files.

To try to make it work you can do the following:

```
#Gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

source 'https://mygemserver.org' do
   gem 'adevdep'
end

#gemspec

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  # Lets say this one comes from RubyGems.org 
  s.add_runtime_dependency 'aruntimedep', '~> 1.0'

  s.add_development_dependency 'adevdep', '~> 0.2'
end
```

Look at issue reported: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/3576